# Sort nested array according to another array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

This are my array

```
$items = array( "100"=>
    array(
        'id' => 15,
        'category' => array('id'=>'100010'),
        'description' => array('type'=>'Drink'),
    ),
    "101"=>
    array(
        'id' => 13,
        'category' => array('id'=>'100055'),
        'description' => array('type'=>'Fruit'),
    ),
    "102"=>
    array(
        'id' => 21,
        'category' => array('id'=>'100002'),
        'description' => array('type'=>'Vege'),
    )
);

$soryBy = array(array('id'=>'100055'),array('id'=>'100002'),array('id'=>'100010'));
```

What are the approach to sort the `$items` `category` according to `$soryBy`? Is there any existing php function i can use??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you are going to want to do is to flatten out your $sortBy array

```
$sortBy = array_map(function($a) { return $a["id"]; }, $sortBy);
```

Then you can use usort with a closure

```
usort($items, function($a, $b) use ($sortBy) {
      return array_search($a["category"]["id"], $sortBy) - array_search($b["category"]["id"], $sortBy);
});
```

Note this solution should work for PHP 5.3 and above.

Comment: I getting error `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array` what are the issue, but i create a manual flatten array in usort it works great!

Comment: i think the issue is that the second parameter to array_map should be $soryBy not $sortBy based on your code